# Run all .exe in a folder

Tags: powershell, cmd, exe

I'm playing with malware in a VM and every script I try gets stuck. Basically I need to run every .exe in a folder. Tried batch files using start, powershell, etc. The issue happens when AV moves some file to quarentine, or some process keep running then the script doesn't jump to the next one.

CMD start works but shows popups when doesn't find some file, then you have to keep clicking to jump to the next file.

These works but get stuck after a while:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\LAB\Desktop\test' | ForEach-Object {
>>   & $_.FullName
>> }
```

Same here:

```
for %%v in ("C:\Users\LAB\Desktop\test\*.exe") do start "" "%%~v"
```

and here:

```
for %%i in (C:\Users\LAB\Desktop\test\*.exe) do %%i
```

Comment: What about using following command line in a batch file? `pushd "C:\Users\LAB\Desktop\test" && ((for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir *.exe /A-D /B 2^>nul') do %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /L /M /C:WhatEver "%%I" >nul 2>nul & if exist "%%I" start "" "%%I") & popd)` I assume that the anti-virus application scans the executable on __FINDSTR__ opening it for searching for the text and moves it to quarantine folder on being evaluated as malware in which case the file does not exist anymore after execution of __FINDSTR__.

Comment: if you're playing with malware then why don't just disable the antivirus? What's the point of running the malware with an AV active? Unless you want to test the AV capability

Comment: I'm testing AVs realtime protection actually.

Comment: @Mofi Thank you, this command worked well too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be looking at something like this:

```
#Assuming the .exe's are located in C Root.
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ | Where-Object {$_.Extension -like ".exe"}| Foreach {Start-Process $_.FullName}

#In Ps, we like to filter as far left as possible for faster results.
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -File "*.exe" | Foreach {Start-Process $_.FullName}

#Running the commands as jobs so it doesnt wait on any to finish before running the next.
Start-Job { Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -File "*.exe" | Foreach {Start-Process $_.FullName} }
Start-Sleep 2
Get-Job | Remove-Job
```